# Not found argument in -exec

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I have such a problem, I'm trying to output a list of movies without the names of directories in the file, but I have a bug, the argument is not found in the `-exeс`, below is the code

```
$ find . -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" -exec basename \{} \ > ~/Bash/test/rm/films.txt
```

Comment: find: there is no argument to "-exec"

Comment: you're missing a `;`.  Also it appears to work for me but I don't believe there is any reason to escape `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
$ find . \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" \) -exec basename {} \; > ~/Bash/test/rm/films.txt
```

Comment: I tried, the same thing

Comment: Thank you very much, your change worked, I so wanted to do, but I thought that after ";" code will not work anymore,
Thanks again, your answer is the best

Comment: When you have multiple conditions, you should use parentheses like here, it's mandatory

Comment: @GillesQuenot It's only "mandatory" if the precedence of the conditions (OR/AND) matter.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I agree

Answer (score 4):

There are two typos in your command.

1. `\{}` should be `{}`
2. The `\␣` (backslash+space) should be `\;` or `';'`.

The `-exec` option/predicate of `find` needs to know where the command that it executes ends. It is told this by the `;` at the end (which needs to be quoted to protect it from the shell).

You should not need to escape or quote `{}`.

There might be some issues with precedence too. You basically say

```
condition OR condition AND run-this-command
```

which is ambiguous. It would be better to say

```
(condition OR condition) AND run-this-command
```

This does that:

```
find . -type f '(' -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' ')' \
    -exec basename {} ';' > ~/Bash/test/rm/films.txt
```

I've also added `-type f` so that only regular files are considered.